# Getting Error 403: Forbidden despite using headers. What could be going wrong?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I'm trying to download a TikTok video off its direct-link and despite adding headers, I still get Error 403. I'm wondering what could be wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
import time

path = "c:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@mrpianoman/video/6962623261184167173?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1"
time.sleep(0.5)

video_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".video-card-one-column.default video").get_attribute("src")
time.sleep(0.5)

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

url = video_link
local = r'C:\Users...'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,local)
```

I get:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I don't know what I could do more.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted my previous correct answer and used it in your question instead of accepting it. It is a good practice to accept correct answers, it makes people more willing to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in india just turn on vpn and continue scraping

Comment: Hello and welcome to the StackOverflow community!
As I see you are a new contributor I highly recommend you take a look at this guide on how to answer a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  Tried headers and had the same problem.  It was very frustrating.  I would have liked to have kept it to urllib, but eventually gave up and used pynput to control the mouse and keyboard inputs.  The code will need to be adjusted for location of video on your screen as well as the "Save Video As" option in the context menu. This will give you a chance to get the X,Y of the mouse position you need:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller as MouseController
import time

mouse = MouseController()

time.sleep(5)
print(mouse.position)
time.sleep(5)
print(mouse.position)
time.sleep(5)
print(mouse.position)
time.sleep(5)
print(mouse.position)
exit()
```

And this will save the video for you with the numbers at the end of the video link as the filename (not shown is the code to set up your webdriver and obtain the video url and video source url):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button
from pynput.mouse import Controller as MouseController

keyboard = Controller()
mouse = MouseController()

driver.get(video_src)
mouse.position = (700,400)
time.sleep(0.1)
mouse.press(Button.right)
mouse.release(Button.right)
time.sleep(0.1)
mouse.position = (750,500)
time.sleep(0.1)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.type(f'C:\\{video_url[-19:]}.mp4')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```